# fs::dir_ls() returns unreadable output for file paths with chinese characters inside

Tags: r, path, fs

I'm using `fs::dir_ls()` to get excel file paths under a directory `main_path`, but since there are Chinese characters in the file paths, I get an unreadable output, I think it's maybe related to encoding issues:

```
main_path <- '../../raw_data/2022-01-10/'
file_paths <- fs::dir_ls(main_path, regexp = ".xlsx") 
file_paths
```

Out:

```
../../raw_data/2022-01-10/閽㈤搧_鐒︾偔_浠峰樊_鐒︾偔J2201DCE鐒︾偔J2205DCE_涓诲姏_2022-01-10.xlsx
../../raw_data/2022-01-10/閽㈤搧_鐒︾偔_浠峰樊_鐒︾偔J2201DCE鐒︾偔J2209DCE_2022-01-10.xlsx
```

While `list.files(path = main_path, pattern ='.xlsx')` returns file names correctly:

```
[1] "甘其毛道库提价含税焦煤A23V2606SG85JM焦煤JM2201DCE_2022-01-10.xlsx"           
  [2] "甘其毛道库提价含税焦煤A23V2606SG85JM焦煤JM2205DCE_2022-01-10.xlsx"
```

The version of `fs` package I use:

```
Warning message:
package ‘fs’ was built under R version 4.1.2
```

Does someone know how to deal with this issue? or if there are equivalent methods to get excel file paths under a directory in R? Thanks.

**Update:**

I didn't find the raison to cause this error, it maybe related to `locale` of RStudio since it works on my Mac but not on Windows 10 machine, I've set `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","zh_CN.utf-8")`, not work either, but I find an alternative solution:

```
file_names <- list.files(path = main_path, pattern ='.xlsx')
file_paths <- file.path(main_path, file_names)
```

Out:

```
[1] "../../raw_data/2022-01-10/甘其毛道库提价含税焦煤A23V2606SG85JM焦煤JM2201DCE_2022-01-10.xlsx"           
  [2] "../../raw_data/2022-01-10/甘其毛道库提价含税焦煤A23V2606SG85JM焦煤JM2205DCE_2022-01-10.xlsx"
```

**Reference:**

https://github.com/r-lib/fs/issues/281

https://github.com/r-lib/fs/issues/164

Comment: What is the result after setting your locale? i.e. `tmcn::setchs()` and then run `fs::dir_ls`? When I create a dummy file the above works

Comment: `tmcn::setchs()` returns `[1] "Chinese (Simplified)_China.936"`

Comment: It seems not working out, I've set `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "zh_cn.utf-8")`, didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is avaliable while the version of `fs` package is higher than `1.5.0`, so downgrade the `fs` to `1.5.0` can fix it with the code:

```
devtools::install_version("fs", "1.5.0")
```